# Hash based routing in react-router-component

Tags: react-router-component

I want to use hash-based routing in react-router-component, so I added the `hash` attribute to the `<Locations>` component like this:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <Locations hash>
    <Location path="/" handler={HomePage} />
    <Location path="/movies/" handler={MoviesPage} />
    <Location path="/movies/:id" handler={MoviePage} />
  </Locations>
</div>
```

I'm linking to this locations like this:

```
<li><Link href="/">Home</Link></li>
<li><Link href="/movies/">Movies</Link></li>
```

I also tried including the hashtags manually in the `Link` component (I can't find it documented anyware how to link to a hash-based route).

```
<li><Link href="/#/">Home</Link></li>
<li><Link href="/#/movies/">Movies</Link></li>
```

The problem is that either way, react-router-component is not responding to clicks on the links. It is updating the url in the browser, but it is not switching to render the component defined as handler in the Location.

When I visit the url manually, e.g. http://localhost:8082/#/movies/, the correct component is being rendered, but again, I can still not navigate.

Also, if I remove the `hash` attribute from the `<Locations>`, linking to routes is working as expected again.

Comment: Hi there, I was having this same problem, were you able to solve it?

Comment: No. Eventually I switched back to react-router again...